# PHP fsockopen connect timeout via browser but not via CLI

Tags: php, curl, fsockopen, connection-timeout, command-line-interface

I'm fighting a bizarre problem and running out of ideas, hope someone here could help me out. It's about random connection timeout to an external server - very frequent when ran from a browser, but very rare when ran from CLI. More details and the code:

On my site `example.com` I have a form. Once a user submits it (HTTP POST), php sends a request (another POST) to an external server `http://external.com/check.php` with some POST-data. Once it gets a response, it proceeds with execution of the rest of the code and outputs a web page in the end. It looks like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST) {
    // here goes some POST validation stuff, and then:
    req = http_build_query($_POST);
    $http_request = "POST /check.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Host: external.com\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
    $http_request .= "User-Agent: SpeciallyDefinedForExternal.com/PHP\r\n";
    $http_request .= "\r\n";
    $http_request .= $req;
}

if (false == ($fs = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10))) {
    throw new Exception($errstr, $errno);
}

fwrite($fs, $http_request);
while (!feof($fs)) {
    $response .= fgets($fs, 1024); // One TCP-IP packet
}
fclose($fs);

// do some stuff depending on on $response
```

Everything works fine when I run it on development server, but once I deploy it to production, it randomly keeps throwing Exceptions at `fsockopen()` call.

I checked in log files that about 15% of `fsockopen()` calls are successful, and the rest are `110 Connection timed out` errors.

**The weirdest thing is, that when I log in to production server and run the very same snippet of code via CLI, then only 0.1% of requests face a connection timeout error, and 99.9% work perfect!** Even if I put in in the loop of 2000 iterations, the ratio stays the same.

I talked with administrators of `external.com` and they said they have only 5% server load, and their other customers do not face any timeout problems, so it looks like this is something with my php or network issue.

Configuration of my development server and production server is identical, the only difference is the load - about 150 requests per second in production. To be clear: these 150 requests are my visiting users, but not each of them submits the form and opens the socket. There are only about 14 such users per second, i.e. there are about 14 POSTs per second sent to `external.com` from my server.

When i tried to replace `fsockopen()` with `curl`, it got better - now about 45% of POSTs sent to `external.com` were successful (via browser) - which is still unsatisfactory. When I run from CLI - it works perfect. And the error message is slightly different, but means actually the same: `couldn't connect to host`.

Any ideas what could be the reason, that requests via browser tend to fail, while those sent via CLI work fine?

If it matters: I'm using php 5.3.27 and my webserver is Apache. The version number is identical when I call `phpinfo()` via browser and `php -v` via CLI.

Thanks in advance,

Pstryk

*** EDIT ***

It turned out to be a problem in their router configuration.

Administrators of `external.com` didn't see any load increase, because they were looking at the wrong machine. The culprit was **their router**, not the server `external.com`.
They have changed something in the router configuration, but refrain from disclosing what setting it was exactly, I guess we'll never find out. Funny thing is, that since they have fixed the issue, now the same problem appears on my development server... but that's something I can live with. To be clear: on my side, development server uses a different router than the production server, but their configuration is the same (except for IPs and so on).
I would like to thank everyone who tried to help me out with this issue. Apparently there was nothing we could do.

Comment: Your server is linux or windows based? It is a shared hosting or dedicated server with assigned bandwidth?

Comment: It is linux based, hosted in my company's own data center. Bandwitdh is very broad and the size of data returned by external.com is less than 100 characters (plus HTTP headers)

Comment: You're talking about 150 requests per second. This is 9000 requests per minute. In less than 7 minutes, you use all server sockets. You should tune your linux system for this kind of load. Moreover, consider keep-alive connections and a small daemon to handle this kind of traffic, you're wasting a lot of network resources with this implementation.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not be clear enough: it is around 150 request per second to my server (example.com), but not every visiting user submits a form and opens a socket. There are only about 14 requests per second to external.com from my server. I'll edit the original question to make this clear.

Comment: Try to raise CURL timeouts to 60 seconds and see what happens. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,60); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); `

Comment: I actually have already tried before to raise the timeout from 10 to 20 seconds - percentage of failures dropped a bit... but the business says that such a long page loading time is unacceptable. On the other hand - when I send the POST to external.com via CLI, the percentage of failures is about 0.1% no matter if the timeout is 60s or 1s. In my opinion this means that timeout is not the culprit here. My main concern is actually what causes that the timeout error is so frequent when script is running via web browser, and so rare when it's running from CLI?

Comment: Increasing timeout was just to test if problem is there. Keep in mind that several parallel requests are different from a 2000 request cycle one after other. Try to run 20 parallel processes from CLI and see if behaviour is the same. I do not expect differences between php module and cli if configuration is the same.

Comment: I ran a loop of 300 iterations, each iteration sending 20 parallel requests. They were all successful. Maybe the problem is triggered by some part of code before the request, or maybe there is some netowork issue causing packet loss... I'll let you know if I find anything. BTW thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to reproduce the same test with php executed from a web page. Use wget to script http requests. If behaviour is different, something fishy is going on.

Comment: I wrote a separate php script which was executed using `shell_exec()` - still it didn't work as expected, i.e. sometimes it was working fine, and sometimes it was receiving a connection timeout. Now I'm about to try something like `shell_exec('curl --data ... http://external.com/check.php')`, I'll let you know if this helped anything. Meanwhile, the router has been replaced with another one, so this rather excludes hardware failure.

Comment: Calling `shell_exec('curl --data ... http://external.com/check.php')` in php script didn't help anything. However, calling `curl --data ... http://external.com/check.php` directly via shell is working fine. Could Apache configuration have anything to do with it? I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: I'm not aware of such a limitation in apache or php. Which linux flavour are you using? Which is your PHP configuration on Apache? Fast cgi or what?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already checked but is the configuration really identical for php-cli, mod_php (dev, stage, live)? It seems like there is a very short timeout configured. This would also explain the different behavior of fsockopen and curl, they have different settings iirc.

Please have a look at: http://php.net/stream_set_timeout in the documentation of fsockopen is noticed that the timeout is just only for opening the socket.

Comment: Yes, all these config files are identical (except for things that must be different).
The first example in http://php.net/stream_set_timeout shows that I need to set the timeout for a connection which is already open, but in my case the connection fails to open due to timeout ;) In other words - it can't establish a connection for which I could set a timeout.